# Laravel Access Denied for IP only

Tags: laravel, windows, github

When I launched a Laravel project from GitHub in the XAMPP folder it runs fine and all shows like it should.

However, when I launch it as a Laravel Homestead project with the homestead IP address as the app url I get an error (pictured here).

I have already added the database and added it in my .env file, it works fine when in the XAMPP folder so I'm not sure why the website wont run in homestead.

Appreciate your help.[screenshot of error code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOV9d.png)

Comment: Did you clear the cache of your laravel application?

Comment: I ran it after a fresh install of homestead and vagrant but I'll see if it works

Comment: We need more detail here. Where is MySQL running now? Homestead? When you updated your .env what did you change?

Comment: I have XAMPP running MySQL and I have Homestead and vagrant running. When I updated the .env I changed the database to one I made in phpmyadmin and when I moved the project to Homestead I changed my APP URL to the homestead IP.

Comment: Homestead runs on the VM so the IP you need to access the host DB will need to be different. You can use the [databases that come with homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#connecting-to-databases) or somehow find what IP the host machine has in the guest.

Answer (score 0):

You have set password in mysql user change `.env` password . If you are using phpmyadmin. use username and password of phpmyadmin in `.env`

Create database in phpmyadmin which is in `.env`

```
DB_DATABASE=hrms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Here databse name is ***hrms***  so you have to create database named hrms

Then migrate it so laravel can create all database table

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: upvote and approve my answer if you find your solution. If you didn't find comment here, i will try to answer as soon as possible.

Comment: you have password set on phpmyadmin right

Comment: That’s what I find weird as I did create a database in phpmyadmin but when I use that database for my env homestead file I’m denied access to view the webpage. However with the same database and password I can view the webpage perfectly when im running on my localhost (when the project is under xampps/htdocs)

Comment: I removed the password for it so password is blank. Should I have a password for it to work on homestead maybe?

Comment: no use password which you used to login phpmyadmin

Comment: homestead is an example so if you want to connect to db you have to use your password. Don't worry it's safe to use.

Comment: I’ll add a password and I’ll provision vagrant right now.

Comment: ok then migrate it and then run your serevr. it will work fine